# Dialog with AlertDialog style

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In my project I need use custom Dialog instead AlertDialog. But I have two problems with Dialog style:

1. Too small width
2. I cannot remove title space

So, I need

[image]

But get:

[image]

Calling code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.write_message);
dialog.show();
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="3" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send_message" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to fix this problems? Help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //for the title space
```

and

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); //for the width
```

You can add padding in the layout xml if you need it

?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Title now is not showing, that's ok. But width doesn't changed. May be this problem have another way to be solved?

Comment: If i remember, the dialog.getWindow().setLayout must be done after the setContentView